# IIS Virtual folder

Tags: iis

Should my IIS Virtual folder point to a local folder or a folder on another machine?

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS is typically used to serve folders that are local / on the same server.  There are scenarios where it might make sense to serve from a network share but in my experience those cases are the exception and not the rule.